# Can I Transfer file to different Windows and linux server simultaneously?

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer

I have a task to transfer the file from application to different server. The destination server may be windows or Linux. Can I handle the code i.e. as per condition the file will sent to respective windows or linux server from same script. Or is there any protocol/tool available which can handle this.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You have tagged this as `ftp` so do you know what `ftp` is? If you run an `ftp` server (or any other file server) on both the Windows and Linux machines then your script can use the same protocol to transfer files to both. The script only needs to know the file transfer protocol and not the OS of the server.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is: yes. "is there any protocol/tool": there are many - ftp, scp, rcp, http, tftp, etc.

Comment: @kaylum do you know any protocol which works on both windows and linux.

Comment: Yes, all the ones I mentioned except maybe not rcp for windows.